# Is it possible to add custom button/s in Sitecore Forms v9.1?

Tags: sitecore-forms

**Sitecore 9.1 with a Sitecore forms(v 9.1)**

We have a requirement to add buttons (like Google Drive or Dropbox) to the Forms which will work similarly to the File Upload element available in the OOTB Forms elements.

Are there any Form extensions that can help? (I have reviewed some but that didn't help)

Is it possible to add custom buttons? If yes, can you give some suggestions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101976/discussion-on-question-by-ruchi-yevle-is-it-possible-to-add-custom-button-s-in-s).

Comment: You can create your own custom form element in Sitecore Form. Please see the below Sitcore blog that would help you in creating custom form element like button. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Follow the steps:

1. Create a new View (.cshtml) on `<webroot>\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates`
2. For a button, I recommend cloning the `<webroot>\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\Button.cshtml` and customizing according to your needs.
3. Create a new item at `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/` and refers the View created in step 2.